# Car payment estimation formula in javascript

Tags: javascript

The Formula looks like this:

```
(25000 x (.06 / 12)) / (1 - ((1 + (.06 / 12))^(-36))) = 760.548436
```

I have been attempting to convert this to javascript but with not much luck. If you put that above formula into google you will see the answer.

After many attempts and different methods, braking up the formula into different variables then dividing them, I haven't had any luck, when I came up with this, it got me the wrong answer:

```
var loan = 25000;
var rate = 6 / 100;
var term = 36;
var calculate = (loan * (rate / 12)) / (1 - ((1 + (rate / 12))^(-term)));
console.log(calculate);
```

Output was:

```
3.4722222222222223
```

And not 760.548436. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this calculation in JavaScript. Anyone can see the formula by viewing the source on the page.

Comment: The formula isn't really a secret though; it's just standard amortization stuff.

Comment: To do powers in JavaScript, use [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow). The caret (`^`) symbol is reserved for an entirely different purpose.

Comment: I did find this, but the function requires 2 parameters and I could not figure out how to incorporate that into this formula, guess I will keep trying.

Comment: `Math.pow(1 + rate / 12, -term)`

Comment: If you wanted to do `2 ^ 3`, you would do `Math.pow(2, 3)`.

Comment: Be aware that Javascript uses `double`s for numbers, a type of evil not "good" for financial calculations. Sadly javascript natively doesn't support anything similar to the `decimal` type.

Answer (score 2):

The caret is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).  You want this formula instead:

```
calculate = (loan * (rate / 12)) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (rate / 12), -term));
```

It gives you the answer you expect, `760.5484362888927`